# Can I get my partner to live with me on a work permit in Germany?

Tags: germany

I recently got a proposal to work in Bonn, Germany; and I was wondering if there is a way for me to legally get my partner some type of visa that lets her travel and live with me until the permit expires. (If it helps I am financially capable of taking care of both of us)

She's planning to enroll in a University there but my period of staying is way beyond the education Visa that she's going to get.

P.S: We're not married nor engaged.

Comment: Depends on the particulars of your case, but you should ask at Expatriates stack exchange.

Comment: https://www.germany-visa.org/family-reunion-visa/